# Java instantiate private variables

Tags: java

Is it a bad practice to instantiate private variable in a class to avoid the NullPointerException when using the variable, for example:

```
public Class MyClass{

private HashMap<String, String> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();


public HashMap<String, String>  getMyHashMap (){return myHashMap;  }
public HashMap<String, String>  setMyHashMap (String myString){ /* treatment to set the myHashMap under some conditions */}
}
```

If we don't instantiate the myHashMap, the method getMyHashMap() may return **null** 
Is it a better practice that the caller of getMyHashMap() checks for the null value? 
Is there a coding good practice to be applied in those circumstances?

Comment: you could always provide a constructor

Comment: Take a look at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/120355/is-it-better-to-return-null-or-empty-values-from-functions-methods-where-the-ret

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly ok.

A common pattern in programming is iterating over a collection or map that is returned from a method. If the method possibly returns `null`, the onus is on the caller to perform a null check before attempting to iterate over the collection or map. Thus, it is normally considered bad practice to return `null` from public methods that return a collection or map. A better alternative would be to return an empty collection or map, as these allow safe iteration without a NullPointerException.

While not recommended, it is ok to return `null` from a private method that returns a collection or map, since their scope is limited to the enclosing class.

Answer (score 3):

I use two solutions for this kind of situations. If `myHashMap` has to be always available, set it as `final` and initialize with value:

```
private final HashMap<String, String> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

public HashMap<String, String> getMyHashMap () {
    return myHashMap;
}
```

If `myHashMap` is something bigger than empty object I rather preffer to do something like a lazy loading:

```
private HashMap<String, String> myHashMap;

public HashMap<String, String> getMyHashMap () {
    if (myHashMap == null) {
        myHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }
    return myHashMap;
}
```

Comment: In case of concurrent access it may result in two callers obtaining references to different maps. I think the second piece of code should be synchronized

Comment: @FilippoFratoni If it is designed to use concurrently, yes. Or you can just document that your class isn't thread safe and requires external synchronization. (Which may be adequate in some cases, not in others.)

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not a bad practice.

By doing this, you are establishing up an invariant for the class: *`myHashMap` is not null*. This invariant makes reasoning about the correct functioning of the rest of the class easier: you know that `myHashMap` is not null, so you won't get `NullPointerException` when you try to access it.

You can implement this by assigning the value in an initializer block (which your code is equivalent to) or assigning the value in the constructor. The two are *roughly* equivalent; actually, assigning the field when you declare it becomes an initializer block, which is executed before the constructor.

You can strengthen your reliance upon this invariant by making `myHashMap` final: this means that you can't accidentally set it to `null` later.

You don't strictly need this invariant: as @hsz suggests, you can make the value non-null lazily. However, I would argue that this clutters the class, and makes it harder to reason about. It's also harder to change the class to add new functionality: you have to remember to add that lazy instantiation to new code if it requires access to `myHashMap`.

I would say it is much better to create it once-and-for-all when you create the instance, and get on with the rest of your code - especially for something as trivial as an empty `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

You could instantiate your map in the constructor.

```
public Class MyClass{

private HashMap<String, String> myHashMap;

public MyClass(){
    myHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
}


public HashMap<String, String>  getMyHashMap (){ return myHashMap;  }
public HashMap<String, String>  setMyHashMap (String myString){ /* treatment to set the myHashMap under some conditions */}
}
```

This way, `getMyHashMap` will never return `null`

Comment: This is functionally equivalent. (So long as you don't create another constructor.)